# 1-forms as a direct sum

Tags: integration, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Let us define the spaces $C_0, C_1$ and $C_2$ of differential $0,1,2$ forms respectively on the sphere $S^2.$

Is it true that $C_1$ is the direct sum of $d(C_0) \oplus \delta^* (C_2)$?  I *think* this is the case, but I'm not sure how to prove it. ($\delta^*$ is the dual operator of $d$, defined via the Hodge star.)

Possibly relevant facts: -since the sphere is simply connected, we know that closed forms are exact (Poincare lemma).
-we know that there are no harmonic 1-forms on the sphere. Hence, given a 1-form $\theta,$ then $d\theta =0$ implies $\delta^* \theta=0.$ If the converse statement were true, then we could use the Poincare lemma to obtain the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand,
$$C_1=d(C_0)\oplus d(C_0)^{\perp}=d(C_0)\oplus\ker d^*$$
On the other hand,
$$C_1=d^*(C_2)\oplus d^*(C_2)^{\perp}=d^*(C_2)\oplus\ker d$$
Since $d(C_0)\subseteq\ker d$, this implies $\ker d=\ker d\cap\left(d(C_0)\oplus\ker d^*\right)=d(C_0)\oplus\left(\ker d\cap\ker d^*\right)$, $\mathrm{H}^1(S^2)=\ker d/ d(C_0)\simeq\ker d\cap\ker d^*$ and
$$C_1=d(C_0)\oplus\left(\ker d\cap\ker d^*\right)\oplus d^*(C_2)$$
But, since $S^2$ is simply connected, $\mathrm H^1(S^2)=0$ and hence
$$C_1=d(C_0)\oplus d^*(C_2)$$